# Empty file shrinks after creating FS

Tags: filesystems, centos7

I have a problem with my Server which freaks me out. I want to create a empty file and mount the file afterwards as a loop device. So I try this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/loop.img bs=1024k count=10
```

When I check the file it has the proper size:

```
ls -lisah
528484126  10M -rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M 31. Mär 04:06 loop.img
```

Next step is to create the fs:

```
mkfs.ext4 /tmp/loop.img
```

and afterwards the file is smaller:

```
ls -lisah
528484126 1,2M -rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M 31. Mär 04:10 loop.img
```

And I'm not able to mount the file. Has anybody an idea what happened, or can tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your biggest problem is that you didn't mount the image via a loop before running mkfs, which you probably meant to do (e.g. `losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/loop.img` followed by `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0`)

But, as to the shrinkage and why the numbers change, the 1.2M is actual file use; the 10M is disk allocation. That's saying "you have granted loop.img 10M on /tmp, and it is currently using 1.2M of them".

Filesystem images are one of the few kinds of files (along with sparsely-allocated files) where that matters; generally disk allocation is just the next block boundary higher than the actual file size.